# WCF 4.0 Security

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I'm new to using WCF and need some help configuring security for a simple WCF 4.0 service.  I want to allow one particular domain user account to be able to access the service and no one else.  I've seen some sample code where the accounts credentials are sent via the proxy in the client application calling the service, like this:
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "MyUsername";
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "MyPassword";
But I can't figure out how to configure the endpoint in my service to accept that user as the only one authorized to use the service.  Here is the code for my endpoint:

```
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="EvalServiceLibrary.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
```

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your `wsHttpBinding` will be using Windows credentials, which works fine in a LAN/corporate intranet environment.

In order to limit who can call your service, you need to decorate your service class (the implementation) with restrictions - this cannot be done in config.

You can define principal permissions on a per-operation (service method) basis

```
public class MyService : IMyServiceContract
{
   [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, User="Domain\\YourUserName")]
   public void Method1() {...}
}
```

In this case, only the user `Domain\YourUserName` can call this method - anyone else will get a security exception.

Read more about the [Fundamentals of WCF Security](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0611051) - especially [page 4](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0611051&page=4) where role-based security is discussed.

Of course, extensibility is one of WCF's hallmark features - and this [gentleman here](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-create-aspnet-windows.html) has created a custom authentication module which allows you to use Windows credentials (users and roles) and define your WCF security settings in your config file.

Comment: Marc, thanks that helps a lot.  It looks like I'm going to need to allow an active directory group to access the service instead of an individual.  Is there decoration for the service for groups?

Comment: @Russ Clark: Yes, I think the `Role="groupname"` should work for that scenario, if you're using Windows credentials. You can also apply multiple of those attributes to allow for multiple users and multiple groups to permit calling the service method